# Какой триггер отвечает за неактивное окно?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как называется триггер неактивного окна?

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>
```

так `IsFocused` не получается изменять цвет границы неактивного окна

Comment: Вы попробуйте без стиля вообще написать у окна `BorderBrush="Red"`, изменится цвет границы?

Comment: да, так меняется `<Style ... <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#222222" />` Но всегда, а мне нужно в то время когда окно не активное

Comment: У меня не меняется. На какой ОС пробуете?

Comment: windows 10. но я пишу внутри отдельного файла стиля style.xaml

Comment: Ах, ну да, надо же еще `BorderThickness` ненулевой, чтобы цвет было видно...

Comment: Используйте свойство `IsActive`, у меня с ним работает. `IsFocused` — это логический фокус, в любом окне, даже неактивном какой-то из элементов находится в фокусе, само окно при этом (если оно имеет focusable-контролы) в фокусе быть не может

Comment: `IsActive` работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте триггер на [свойство `IsActive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.isactive), именно оно отвечает за активность окна.

[Свойство `IsFocused`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isfocused) отвечает за *логический* фокус, т. е. в любом окне (даже неактивном) какой-то из контролов обязательно находится в фокусе и именно у него установлено это свойство, у всех остальных контролов при этом это свойство сброшено. Таким образом, если у вас в окне есть хоть один контрол, способный получить логический фокус, само окно никогда не будет иметь этот фокус у себя.